# Ensuring a GROUP has specific values, no more no less with an aggregate

Tags: postgresql, select, aggregate, array

I have a table `(a :: text, b :: uuid)`.

I also have a **set** (not a list, i.e. *order* doesn’t matter) of UUIDs, `bs = {b1, b2, b3}`.

How can I get such an `a` that has exactly those three `bs` in the table, no more and no less?

Something like:

```
SELECT tt.a
  FROM (SELECT a, sort(array_agg(b)) AS bs FROM t GROUP BY a) AS tt
  WHERE tt.bs = sort('{b1, b2, b3}')
```

But that seems like quite a bad idea w.r.t. efficiency…

Comment: How about some DDL and sample data, and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this..

```
SELECT a
FROM tt
GROUP BY a
HAVING array_agg(b ORDER BY b) = ARRAY[
  -- whatever
]::uuid[];
```

sample data,

```
CREATE TABLE tt ( a text, b uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() );
INSERT INTO tt(a) VALUES ('foo'), ('bar'), ('baz'), ('foo'), ('foo');

SELECT a, b FROM tt ORDER BY a,b;
  a  |                  b                   
-----+--------------------------------------
 bar | 6a7d1d36-d16f-459c-9fb0-b5a54f1fc5b3
 baz | 2fca5dee-4bfe-4862-9b8a-79890fbfda28
 foo | 32f9d608-f87f-4830-b0d8-6215f60a71ee
 foo | 3fe0cffe-446e-4e94-8785-2f893ee91a0c
 foo | f9d07c5a-e69b-4501-a441-5bbd86ed7f4b
(5 rows)
```

This will return `foo`,

```
SELECT a
FROM tt
GROUP BY a
HAVING array_agg(b ORDER BY b) = ARRAY[
  '32f9d608-f87f-4830-b0d8-6215f60a71ee',
  '3fe0cffe-446e-4e94-8785-2f893ee91a0c',
  'f9d07c5a-e69b-4501-a441-5bbd86ed7f4b'
]::uuid[];
```

However, without exactly those three things and nothing more in the `array_agg` and in that order and you won't get a match.

If you don't care about excess matches, that is to say if foo having addition UUIds should return a match you can optimize this expression by copying them into an additional where clause which will use an index.

Shy of that, if you need faster you could move to use Materialized Views, or write a count clause too...

```
HAVING count(*) = ...
  AND array_agg(b ORDER BY b) = ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you got it absolutely right, that’s what I want. Sorry for the lack of DDL/data/output. I don’t want excess matches, either.

Comment: So can we make this fast, somehow indexing `b` cleverly? Are materialized views the only option?

Comment: If you want to potentially speed it up, you could do HAVING `count(*) = number AND array_agg(b ORDER BY b) = ...` but you'd have to statically type that up.

Comment: I can do that, thanks for that suggestion! I’m a bit afraid of materialized views, because Postgres can’t do them incrementally… Hmmm.

Comment: Also I could select not from the whole `tt`, but pre-select `a`s that have one of the `b`. This way, full scan would be reduced to that significantly smaller (than the whole table) subquery.